# setInterval is not working with innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, setinterval, innerhtml, stopwatch

I  am trying to create a small place on my website to show the seconds running. but my javascript function is not running. At the same time, it does not show any error. This is my javascript code:

```
function stoptime() {
    let count = 0;
    count = count+1;
    stop = document.getElementById("time");
    stop.iinnerHTML = count.value;

setInterval(stoptime, 1000);
```

I can use this code with document.write function, but it did not give the count ++ value, instead of that it showed many single value of count. so I tried to use it with innerHtml, but it not running.

please tell, what is the reason and the correct code?

Comment: `let count = 0;
    count = count+1;` runs every time ... so count will always be `1` --- put the `let count = 0` OUTSIDE the function ... also, a Number (which is what `count`  is) does NOT have a `.value` property ... and `stop.iinnerHTML` should be `stop.innerHTML` - which may explain why nothing **appears** to be happening

Comment: Instead of count.value it must be count only !. Also declare count as global variable not local  i.e `let  count 
= 0 ` variablee must not be inside function

Comment: Adding to above comment, what is count.value? From the code, we can see that count is not an object. Also, "iinnerHTML", two ii. Is this a typo in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <span id="time"></span>
```

**JS**

```
  let count = 0;
  function stoptime() {
    count++
    stop = document.getElementById("time");
    stop.innerHTML = count;
  }

  setInterval(stoptime, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The count variable is initialized in the same function every time. Its value gets reset to 1 each time the function is called. Moving the **count** declaration outside the function should fix your issue.

Also you don't need *count.value*

```js
let count = 0;
function stoptime() {
    count = count+1;
    stop = document.getElementById("time");
    stop.innerHTML = count;
}
setInterval(stoptime, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```